# trying to use jQuery switchClass to create a reveal animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to get an element to change its class to one with a different height attribute to make a reveal effect. I'm just getting an error which says uncaught type error undefined is not a function.

html -

```
<div id="rollup" class="header-container">
    <header class="wrapper clearfix">
    <h1 class="title"></h1>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                   <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
    </header>
<p class="btnRetract">
see more

</p><!--end div retract -->

</div><!--end div rollup-->
```

Javascript -

```
$(".btnRetract").on("click", function() {
var $content = $("#rollup");
switchClasses($content);
     
return false;
 
function switchClasses($content){
if($content.hasClass("header-container")){ 
$content.switchClass("header-container", "header-container-retracted");
}
else {
$content.switchClass("header-container-retracted", "header-container");
}
}
```

CSS -

```
.header-container {
    border-bottom: 20px solid #e44d26;
    height: 90vh;
    position:relative;
}

.header-container-retracted {
    border-bottom: 20px solid #e44d26;
    height: 20vh;
    position:relative;
}
```

Comment: jQuery has no `switchClass` method. Visit the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com) to find valid methods.

Comment: ...and FYI, you don't need all that code. Just use `.toggleClass` and provide both class names. `$("#rollup").toggleClass("header-container header-container-retracted")` This'll work as long as you know the element will always have one or the other class.

Answer (score 0):

That's because `switchClass` is not a function defined by the jQuery plugin. It is actually part of the [jQuery UI framework](http://api.jqueryui.com/switchclass/). However, if you need to "switch" classes using the jQuery plugin you can use either `toggleClass`, `removeClass` and `addClass`. Furthermore, you can even use `animate` to customise the transitions between property values

Answer (score 0):

You dont need a switchClass function (doesnt exist anyway and is causing your error)

You can use answer from squint or.if you dont want to check.for the existence of one of the classes you can do this all in one line:

```
    $content.removeClass('header-container').addClas('header-container-retracted');
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, it would be easier to use the jQuery toggle method, but there are other issues as well with your Javascript and CSS.  Here's a working demo that you can use as an example.

## [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jme11/mt691a6t/)

**Javascript:**

```
$(".btnRetract").on("click", function() {
    $("#rollup").toggleClass('header-container-retracted');
});
```

That's all you need for the click handler if you're using the built in toggleClass method.  It accepts one string as an argument, which is the name of the class that you want to toggle.  You can also have a comma separated list of two class names, wherein it will toggle between the two classes, but in this case, you don't need to swap the classes.  You simply want to add or remove your `.header-container-retracted` class, because your `.header-container` class has all of your base styles in it.  The `.header-container-retracted` class only has to contain the properties you want to override in the base styles and as long as it is **AFTER** your base `.header-container` class in your stylesheet, the normal cascading behavior of CSS will ensure that its properties will override the base properties.

**CSS:**

```
.header-container {
    position: relative;
    border-bottom: 1.5em solid #e44d26;
    height: 85vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-transition: height 1s ease;
    transition: height 1s ease;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 1em;
}

.header-container-retracted {
    height: 3.5em;
}
```

So, in your CSS, you don't need to repeat any of your styles in the .header-container-retracted.  Note also, that I added overflow: hidden to the base styles.  Without this, your content "inside" the header-container element would just spill out and be visible when the header-container was "retracted".  Also, I add some transitions to give the opening and closing a nice smooth animation.  The transitions will not be supported in IE8 or IE9, but they will not prevent the opening/closing of the element.  As @Leo pointed out, if the animation is important to you in IE8/IE9 browsers, you can use jQuery's animate method to handle the transitions instead.

Finally, you'll note in the demo that I set your `.btnRetract`element absolute positioning.  Because you're using relative heights, you need to ensure that your toggle button is always visible.  On a very small viewport, 20vh would be so small that it would obscure the button and make it impossible to expand the header-container.